# What is the image of $\sin(1/x)\cdot(1/x)$, $0<x<1?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

> What is the image of $\sin(1/x)\cdot(1/x)$, $0<x<1?$

I just had a question about what the image of $\sin(1/x)\cdot(1/x)$ is for $0<x<1$. Would it not be all the reals, since $\sin(1/x)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ and $1/x$ hits all the reals?

Comment: That seems a good intuitive argument to me, though you could make it more precise by looking at what happens at $\frac{1}{(2n-\frac12)\pi}$ and $\frac{1}{(2n+\frac12)\pi}$ and between them as $n$ increases

Comment: $1/x$ hits all reals of absolute value $>1$.

Comment: Equivalently you can look at $t\sin t$ for $t>1$.

Comment: The image is necessarily an interval. Look for max and min of $t \sin t, t>1$.

Comment: A somewhat rigorous argument could be made by observing that $sin(1/x)$ completes infinitely many cycles as $x$ goes to $0$ and these cycles get multiplied by $1/x$ which goes to infinity as $x$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the image (range) of the function $\sin(1/x)\cdot(1/x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Your argument is correct. As $x$ goes to $0$, $1/x$ becomes large and goes towards $\infty$. $\sin(1/x)$ oscillates more and more quickly, but it always sits in the range of $[-1,1]$, which makes the graph alternating between being very positive and very negative. (Plot shown in the link.)

I verified the result using Wolfram Mathematica, and indeed, the range is $(-\infty, \infty)$. (In the output, "True" means all real numbers.)

See: [Function Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNKoi.png)

See: [Verification with Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuOGh.png)

Answer (score 1):

The image is indeed $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that in your original post, $\frac1x$ takes all positive values greater or equal to $1$ over the domain $(0,1)$. But yup, good intuition.

Let $f(x) = \frac1x \sin \frac1x, 0< x<1$.

Notice that  $\forall n \ge 1$, $0<\frac1{(2n-\frac12)\pi}<1$ and $0<\frac1{(2n+\frac12)\pi}<1$. We have

$$f\left( \frac1{(2n-\frac12)\pi}\right)=\left(2n-\frac12\right)\pi\sin\left( \left(2n-\frac12\right)\pi\right)=- \left(2n-\frac12\right)\pi$$

$$f\left( \frac1{(2n+\frac12)\pi}\right)=\left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi\sin\left( \left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi\right)= \left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi$$

Since $f$ is continuous, for any $n$, any value between $\left(- \left(2n-\frac12\right)\pi, \left(2n+\frac12\right)\pi\right)$ can be attained.

SInce we can let $n$ take arbitrarily large value, any value in $\mathbb{R}$ can be attained.